# Task not registered error with Flask and Celery

Tags: python, flask, celery

I am using a celery chord and some of the tasks in the header are successful and some fail with the error:

`celery.backends.base.ChordError: NotRegistered("'app.tasks.grab_articles'",)`

However, when my Celery worker loads, I see the task loading as such:

```
(latentcall)
2017-06-21T22:24:04.505411+00:00 app[worker.1]: ---- **** ----- 
2017-06-21T22:24:04.505412+00:00 app[worker.1]: --- * ***  * -- Linux-3.13.0-121-generic-x86_64-with-debian-stretch-sid 2017-06-21 22:24:04
2017-06-21T22:24:04.505413+00:00 app[worker.1]: -- * - **** --- 
2017-06-21T22:24:04.505414+00:00 app[worker.1]: - ** ---------- [config]
2017-06-21T22:24:04.505415+00:00 app[worker.1]: - ** ---------- .> app:         app:0x7f3db1959208
2017-06-21T22:24:04.505418+00:00 app[worker.1]: - ** ---------- .> transport:   amqp://...
2017-06-21T22:24:04.505419+00:00 app[worker.1]: - ** ---------- .> results:     postgres:...
2017-06-21T22:24:04.505420+00:00 app[worker.1]: - *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 1 (prefork)
2017-06-21T22:24:04.505421+00:00 app[worker.1]: -- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
2017-06-21T22:24:04.505421+00:00 app[worker.1]: --- ***** ----- 
2017-06-21T22:24:04.505422+00:00 app[worker.1]:  -------------- [queues]
2017-06-21T22:24:04.505423+00:00 app[worker.1]:                 .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery
2017-06-21T22:24:04.505423+00:00 app[worker.1]:                 
2017-06-21T22:24:04.505424+00:00 app[worker.1]: 
2017-06-21T22:24:04.505425+00:00 app[worker.1]: [tasks]
2017-06-21T22:24:04.505425+00:00 app[worker.1]:   . app.tasks.calculate_best_matches
2017-06-21T22:24:04.505426+00:00 app[worker.1]:   . app.tasks.grab_articles
```

My app is set up the same was the app here:

https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/flasky-with-celery

Here's the structure of my app:

```
proj
 |---app
   |---__init__.py
   |---tasks.py
 |---celery_worker.py
 |---config.py
 |---manage.py
```

`__init__.py`

```
from celery import Celery
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from config import Config

db = SQLAlchemy()
celery = Celery(__name__, broker=Config.CELERY_BROKER_URL, backend=Config.CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND)

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(Config)
    Config.init_app(app)

    db.init_app(app)
    celery.conf.update(app.config)

    from .main import main as main_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(main_blueprint)

    return app
```

tasks.py

```
from . import celery
from sqlalchemy.sql import select
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import pairwise_distances
from datetime import datetime
import os
import json
import redis
import pandas as pd
from . import helpers
from . import models

r = redis.from_url(os.environ['REDIS_URL'])

@celery.task(name='task_grab_articles', bind=True)
def grab_articles(self, ids):
    print(self.request.id)
    article = models.Article
    query = article.query.with_entities(article.id, article.tfidf).filter(article.id.in_(ids)).all()
    df = pd.DataFrame(query, columns=['id', 'tfidf']).to_json()
    return query
```

celery_worker:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from app import celery, create_app

app = create_app()
app.app_context().push()
```

manage.py

```
from app import create_app

app = create_app()
```

Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn manage:app
worker: celery worker --app=celery_worker.celery --loglevel=info --concurrency=1
```

After doing some debugging I found that Celery was creating 8 tasks and only sending three or four to my worker process (see Procfile) and once those four were completed my callback task would respond to .ready() with True. However, the other four tasks would still be PENDING when I checked my celery_taskmeta table. These four tasks are not visible anywhere except for the backend. I wonder if they are getting sent to some mystery worker/node that get generated due to multiprocessing.

Comment: Please add example code of how you register grab_articles function in celery and how you invoke it.

Comment: Thanks Fian! I have added the basic structure and contents of files.

Comment: Still can't see how you invoke `grab_articles`. Check your code for [this problem](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#automatic-naming-and-relative-imports).